# Is there a way to stop apache kafka consumer to read messages if the messages are not being processed by other service

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I’m using apache kafka in my project.
So, I’ve a producer which is producing messages to a particular topic.

And consumer is another microservice which is reading messages from kafka and passing that message to another microservice(say data)

Now, the issue is. .. if the final microservice(data) is not working and the consumer is trying to send the message to this service. It should stop reading from kafka and then resend these messages again in the next run.

Do anyone have any idea how to achieve this?

Note - i have tried enable.auto.commit=false

But it did not work

ATTACHING code -
properties -

```
Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", CONFIG_NODE.getSubNode("config")
                .getStringWithDefault("kafkaservers",servers ).get()
                );
        props.put("group.id", group);
        props.put("key.deserializer",StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put("value.deserializer",StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put("enable.auto.commit", "false");
```

java side-

```
ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer
                    .poll(time);
            System.out.println("::::::::::" + records.count());
            for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
                readConsumerRecord(record);
                
            }
consumer.commitSync();
```

Comment: Please include the consumer implementation code in the question

Comment: `enable.auto.commit=false` can be the right approach. What did not work with this approach?

Comment: @AnkitSahay - The consumer is not able to  re-read messages even after i set the enable.auto.commit=false .

Answer (score 0):

> It should stop reading from kafka

Then... Stop the poll loop?

You'll need some healthcheck on the downstream services. But Kafka consumers only read if you're polling.

You're asking how to implement a circuit breaker pattern, which Kafka doesn't natively offer.

> resend these messages again in the next run.

You need to first disable auto commits, then you can either you  restart your consumer or use seek method to do that.

---

Ideally, you turn your consumer into a producer as well.

Make your "final microservice" consume from Kafka rather than accept service-to-service requests, as you're doing now.

Or, use some process orchestration with a load balancer to ensure that your final service is highly available, and run multiple instances.

Comment: I can not do that. I have to try it via consumer

Comment: That's exactly what I said. Make the last service a consumer. Otherwise, you'll end up losing events when it's down for an extended period of time